# Django don't create new sqlite table for new app model

Tags: python, django

pretty new to Django, i'm encountering an issue with a new model (and a new app 'blog' i made). The table blog_post didn't exist after configuring the model and makemigration.

Here is the all process i did. I'm following official tutorial:

Here is my blog/models.py:

```
from django.db import models

    class Post(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=80)
        text = models.TextField()
        author = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', on_delete= models.CASCADE)
        created_date = models.DateTimeField()
        pub_date = models.DateTimeField()

    def publish():
        self.pub_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()
```

mysite/settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
]
```

After the first

> python manage.py makemigrations blog

```
Migrations for 'blog':
blog\migrations\0001_initial.py
- Create model Post
```

> python manage.py sqlmigrate blog 0001

```
BEGIN;
--
-- Create model Post
--
CREATE TABLE "blog_post" ("id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,     "title" varchar(80) NOT NULL, "text" text NOT NULL, "created_date" datetime NOT NULL, "pub_date" datetime NOT NULL, "author_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "auth_user" ("id") DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED);
CREATE INDEX "blog_post_author_id_dd7a8485" ON "blog_post" ("author_id");
COMMIT;
```

> python manage.py migrate

```
Operations to perform:
Apply all migrations: admin, auth, blog, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
No migrations to apply.
```

So, here it is. The new table didn't seem to be created. I check with a SqLite utility and the is no such table: blog_post
I also check with django shell.

I double (triple) check the process:

1. Change your models (in models.py).
2. Run python manage.py makemigrations to create migrations for those changes
3. Run python  manage.py migrate to apply those changes to the database

But i'm stuck at this point. Can someone tell me what i missed ? Thank you !

Here is my database settings:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

> python manage.py showmigrations

```
admin
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_logentry_remove_auto_add
auth
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_alter_permission_name_max_length
 [X] 0003_alter_user_email_max_length
 [X] 0004_alter_user_username_opts
 [X] 0005_alter_user_last_login_null
 [X] 0006_require_contenttypes_0002
 [X] 0007_alter_validators_add_error_messages
 [X] 0008_alter_user_username_max_length
 [X] 0009_alter_user_last_name_max_length
blog
 [X] 0001_initial
contenttypes
 [X] 0001_initial
 [X] 0002_remove_content_type_name
sessions
 [X] 0001_initial
```

I check if table exist with DB Browser for SQLite, but blog_post don't exist.

Link to the github repo: https://github.com/mothinx/juliengracia

Comment: have you tried running `python manage.py makemigrations` without the `blog` inside the command?

Comment: No changes detected is the result.

Comment: The migration is created but not applied. `python manage.py migrate blog` should do it.

Comment: python manage.py migrate blog  
Operations to perform:  
  Apply all migrations: blog  
Running migrations:  
  No migrations to apply.

Comment: Are you sure the table doesn't exist? How are you checking? What are your database settings? Where are you running this code?

Comment: What's the result of `manage.py showmigrations` ?

Comment: i edited the end of my post to show you database settings, and showmigrations command. I'm using those commands in the root folder of my project "juliengracia"

Comment: Here is the github repo: https://github.com/mothinx/juliengracia

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The output of `showmigrations` shows that Django thinks the initial blog migration ran.

```
blog
 [X] 0001_initial
```

The `sqlmigrate` output shows that the migration should have created the table. Therefore it looks as if the `django_migrations` folder and the database are out of sync.

You could try re-running the initial migration by faking back to the zero migration.

```
python manage.py migrate --fake blog zero
python manage.py migrate blog
```

If that doesn't work, and you don't have any important data in the database, you could delete the `db.sqlite3` file and run `python manage.py migrate` again.

Comment: `python manage.py migrate --fake blog zero`  did the trick.For my culture, this option --fake crush the fact that django though table was created ? Thanks a lot man !

Comment: Glad that worked. I'm not sure I understand your follow up question. If you did `python manage.py migrate blog zero` (without `--fake`), then Django would try to reverse the migration by dropping the tables. That would fail because the tables didn't exist. You use `--fake` so that Django updates the `django_migrations` table without trying to update the database. Then when you run `python manage.py migrate blog`, it will run the `0001_initial` migration and create the table.

Answer (score 0):

```
python manage.py migrate --fake APPNAME zero
```

And then you can run the migrate script

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

I just use the following:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: If the problem was with indentation none (or almost none) of the `manage.py` command would work, and specially not `makemigrations`.

Comment: Then I guess it was problem with copy pasting the code. My bad. I will delete my answer.